# requestSingleUpdate not working on Oreo

Tags: android, gps, location, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I have developed an app which sends me location for single time, Everything was working fine but I am not receiving locations in Oreo device.Location permission is provided and GPS is also turned on

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                Log.d(TAG, "requestSingleUpdate: ");
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                        callback.onSomethingWrong("Status Changed" + status);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        callback.onSomethingWrong("Provider Enabled " + provider);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        callback.onSomethingWrong("Provider Disabled" + provider);
                    }
                }, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

`requestSingleUpdate` was [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestSingleUpdate(android.location.Criteria,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) in API 30.

> Use getCurrentLocation(java.lang.String,
> android.os.CancellationSignal, java.util.concurrent.Executor,
> java.util.function.Consumer) instead as it does not carry a risk of
> extreme battery drain.

Looking at https://medium.com/@priyavrat.acharya01/using-new-on-demand-location-update-api-introduced-in-android-11-69c65b3787aa we can see:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    // Fetching the one time current location.
    val locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    // Handle runtime location permission, before calling this method, otherwise it will through the SecurityException.
    // Provider, executor and Consumer<Location> cannot be passed null.
    // CancelationRequest object can be passed as null.          
    locationManager.getCurrentLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, null, this.mainExecutor, locationCallback)
} else {
    // Keep using the legacy code, such as LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()
}

private val locationCallback = Consumer<Location> { location ->
    location?.let {
        Timber.d("Latitude: ${it.latitude.toString()}, longitude: ${it.longitude.toString()}")
    }
}
```

I didn't have problems with `requestSingleUpdate` on Oreo. I didn't test the code, because also migrated to `FusedLocationProviderClient`. `getCurrentLocation` won't work before API 30.

Answer (score 1):

LocationManager APIs, like requestSingleUpdate, are obsolete for Oreo: you have to use **FusedLocationProviderClient** instead.

You can refer to [google developer tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/location/). Particularly, for migration: 
[Migrate to location and context APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/migration)

My tests confirm that the fix is backwards-compatible (tested also with Android 6)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you have permissions? Location is considered a dangerous permission and as such should be requested at run time. See more here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous

Comment: yup, It is working in Marshmellow and nougat, As I have mentioned it was working fine but not working in OREO.
thanks

Comment: @aminpinjari are you requesting permissions dynamically? Can you share code for permissions? Which device are you testing on?